# Should I give preferential treatment to proxy users on my ecommerce site?

Tags: ecommerce, proxy

I am setting up an ecommerce site that caters to a worldwide audience. I would imagine that visitors would come from everywhere, and for whatever reasons, some would be connecting through proxy servers.

My site uses a server that is configured to rate limit connections from the same ip address to protect itself from a DOS attack. So, if a proxy server is heavily used by my visitors, then it would appear to be a DOS.

This is problematic in a sense that it is hard to tell whether the users are genuinely browsing my site or if a DOS is taking place. So my question is, should I give preferential treatment to proxy users on my ecommerce site? If yes, how should this be done. If not, why not?

Comment: I am not sure why you think a user coming through a proxy is normal or good especially for an e-commerce site. Proxies are generally the first thing blocked as a matter of security.

Answer (score -1):

"If a proxy server is heavily used by visitors" means visitors are using same IP address and not coming for buying products or any item they have different purpose to visit your site. A real user does not use proxy to visit any website specially for eCommerce website.

Proxy users are not useful for eCommerce site.

Comment: Quote: "A real user does not use proxy to visit any website" WHAT??

Comment: There are many reasons someone is using a proxy, most of them not implying that their intentions are bad.

Comment: But keeping in mind that most of the users don't even know what a proxy is, you can fairly safely asume that most dont use proxies, and the few who do arent gonna trigger a DOScheck...